# how to get mouse input in python and pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get mouse button input in pygame but it doesn't work. I've tried

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == True:
    "do something"
```

,

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1,0,0):
    "do something"
```

,

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    "do something"
```

...

I think everything from the docs but it does nothing and the `if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1,0,0):` always worked before. 
(`if mouse_pos == (PlayCoordsx, PlayCoordsy) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0):`)
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, it is not recommended to use mouse.get_pressed(). Instead use event.get() and check what the events are. Eg.

```
while ... # This is your main loop
  # get all recent events
  events = pygame.event.get()

  # proceed events
  for event in events:

    # handle MOUSEBUTTONUP, ie. click release
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

      #Do your stuff
```

Comment: *it is not recommended to use mouse.get_pressed()*: Why?

Comment: Not unless you absolutely have to, because you will need to start using flags and stuff to compensate for the multitude of triggers it will generate. And you are likely to miss a lot of presses as you wont have a queue of inputs. Just use get event in the main loop instead, it's more elegant and less error prone. Even the pygame docks for get_pressed() says it's better to use event.get() instead